# Plotting unordered points as a contourf in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7, contourf

I have a list of dictionaries containing unordered data points:

```
print(data)
[{'ID': 1, 'Longitude': 18.6081, 'Latitude': 50.0977, 'Cost': -1.0}, 
{'ID': 2, 'Longitude': 18.6091, 'Latitude': 50.197700000000005, 'Cost': 4},
{'ID': 3, 'Longitude': 18.6081, 'Latitude': 50.297700000000006,'Cost':4},....]
```

I want to plot the value of 'cost' function as countorf using matplotlib.

So far I've tested the following code:

```
   lat = []
   lon = []
   cost = []
   for dataPoint in data:
       if dataPoint["Cost"] == -1:
           continue

       lon.append(dataPoint["Longitude"])
       lat.append(dataPoint["Latitude"])
       cost.append(dataPoint["Cost"])


   xi = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon))
   yi = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat))
   zi = griddata(lon, lat, cost, xi, yi, interp='linear')

   #make a plot
   plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 100)
   plt.colorbar()
   plt.show()
```

Above code works but It interpolates the values between data points and all I want to do is plot all points from data array on a plane with a color coresponding to it's 'cost' value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
In [41]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ; from scipy.interpolate import griddata           
In [42]: import numpy as np                                                               
In [43]: N = 300                                                                          
In [44]: x = np.random.rand(N) ; y = np.random.rand(N)                                    
In [45]: z = np.sin(x*10)+np.cos(y*4)+0.05*np.random.rand(N)                              
In [46]: xi = yi = np.linspace(0,1)                                                       
In [47]: zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')                                  
In [48]: plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 10) ;     
In [49]: plt.scatter(x, y, c=z) ;                                                              
In [50]: plt.colorbar() ;
```

[image]

Comment: `griddata` is now located at `scipy.interpolate.griddata`